# Check my string for numbers. Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, numbers

So I'm writting program that should check my string for numbers and return only the first number in string (as int). 
 Is there a method that checks strings for numbers? 
 And if so, how can I make sure it'll return just the first one?  
 
For example, this string "This string contains numbers 456 but also 5 and 34" should return only 456.

Comment: I think you want to use a regular expression here.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem and an easy one at that.

Comment: What if the string was "test123 456" would it return 123 or 456?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_first_num(text):
    words = text.split()

    for word in words:
        if word.isdigit():
            return word


print get_first_num('This string contains numbers 456 but also 5 and 34')
```

Will return 456

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "sdasdas 12313 dsada 9"
m = re.search(r'\d+', s)
print m.group()
```

If you don't want to match words having digits within:

```
m = re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d+(?!\d)', s)
```

Comment: You may need to check that the number is not part of a string (ie: "test123 456" should not return 123 but instead 456). But that will require OP's clarification.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps...

```
s = "sdasdas 12313 dsada 9 dsgrdfgd"
for _ in s.split():
    if _.isdigit():
        print int(_[:1])
```

Comment: it will be printing the integers out of the string when is found.